# Pop out two frames side by side

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe

I want when pressed a Button on my Jframe to setVisible false the existing Frame and create two other Frames.The theme is I want these two Frames to be popped side by side not the one on top of the other, any clue how I can make this happen.

Comment: First I would check it [multiple frames, good/bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Good to know, it made me rethink my project, but also for the means of curiosity is there any way of doing that

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Buttons, Atkins or frames?

Comment: Thx for your interest I am ok I figured it out all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jframe1.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
jframe2.setBounds(x+jframe1.getWidth(), y, width2, height2);
```

width and width2 can be the same if you want, so can height an height2

Comment: Set location maybe, but setting the size is [*not* good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).  Instead pack the respective top level components and then get the width/height to decide where to locate each window.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated what I could from your answer without going off topic.